# In java8 using Files.walk API, unable to read files from the folder using absolute path

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to read list of files using Files.walk api with relevant path in java8, while I am getting java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \src\main\resources\eclipseconftemplates\java, 
The same api is working with actual paths

Getting exception.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("/src/main/resources/eclipseconftemplates/java"))) {
            paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

working fine:

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\XXXX\\maven_project_demo\\antToMaven\\src\\main\\resources\\eclipseconftemplates\\java"))) {
            paths
                .filter(Files::isRegularFile)
                .forEach(System.out::println);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Did you try printing the value returned by this part of the code you posted: `Paths.get("/src/main/resources/eclipseconftemplates/java")` ?

Comment: Try with `Files.walk(Paths.get("src/main/resources/eclipseconftemplates/java")))`

Comment: _**Warning:** You appear to be accessing resources as normal files. This may work when executing your code in an IDE, but will likely break once your code is packaged in a JAR file._

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't have the prefixed `/` in your directory, otherwise the program will start at the root of the filesystem.

```
try (Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk(Paths.get("src/main/resources/eclipseconftemplates/java"))) {
```

Answer (score 2):

You are getting an error because the system can't resolve the file path you are referring to.
The file separator is system dependent. This is "/" on UNIX and "\" on Windows. 
Always use [System Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) if you want to work platform independent.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator");
```

Comment: The slash will always be converted to the proper path separator.